# Install pywin32 with pip in Windows 7 does not work in python 3.4.2

Tags: python, pip, pywin32

Hy@everybody,

i've try to install pywin32 via pip (1.5.6) with python 3.4.2 under Windows 7, but i've always got the follwing error-message:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywin32
Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external pywin32 to all
ow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pywin32
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\tonka\pip\pip.log
```

All other installations with pip works absolutely fine. On pypi.org, there is an package for pywin32, so don't really understand why this is happening.

I've also tried this --allow-external flag, but then i got the following error

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywin32
Some insecure and unverifiable files were ignored (use --allow-unverified pywi
n32 to allow).
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pywin32
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\tonka\pip\pip.log
```

Then i used the --allow-unverified flag and i get this error

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pywin32
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pywin32
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\tonka\pip\pip.log
```

**Is there a package in pip for pywin32 for 3.4? [pypi-link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywin32/214)**

**Does anybody has the same problem/behavior?**

**Edit**:

For anybody who is searching for a way to install pywin32 via pip. Use the package **[pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32/219)** instead of pywin32, it is the same package, but it is pip-able

Greetings
Tonka

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.win32-py3.4.exe/download (Unless you really want to install from Pip)

Comment: also have this "Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32" WIndows 8, 64 bit

Comment: Please put your edit as an answer and accept it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to your first question, it appears that there is not a pip pywin32 package for python 3.4. If you take a look at this page: url https://pypi.python.org/simple/pywin32/, you can see that there is a `214_download_url`. This indicates that version 214 is the latest available, and the 214 download directory [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20214/) does not contain an installer for anything later than python 3.1.

In answer to your second question, yes, I see the same problem/behaviour with python 3.4.1. As mentioned by @sk11 in a comment, you can download an installer from [here](http://cznic.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pywin32/pywin32/Build%20219/pywin32-219.win32-py3.4.exe). (I can't add a comment because I don't have the rep.) I've just tried the installer and it appears to work fine.

Comment: Hey Captain Whippet,
thanks for your answer.I will choose the installer version of pywin32 instead of pip as sk11 said.
Thx

Comment: @tonka No problem. If you think my answer answers both parts of your question, please mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: New versions are available over sourceforge now. https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/

Comment: Any idea for Python 3.5.2.. I downloaded all version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/, none of one not working.